# How to use UIActivityViewController, sharing data from HTML parsing out the article (article contains images and forms)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

Here is my code:

How to sharing data from html parsing ?

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[webView] applicationActivities:nil];
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPad"]) {
    UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityVC];
    [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
} else {
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This is my image data

`<p style='font-family:宋体;font-size:13.8pt;word-wrap:break-word;text-align:justify;letter-spacing:0.1em;LINE-HEIGHT:1.3;  '>Schematic diagram </p><img style='width:100%;' src='http://114.255.183.85:8080/infoPush/statics/content/14888508222440.jpg'/><p style='font-family:宋体;font-size:13.8pt;word-wrap:break-word;text-align:justify;letter-spacing:0.1em;LINE-HEIGHT:1.3;  '> </p><p style='font-family:宋体;font-size:13.8pt;word-wrap:break-word;text-align:justify;letter-spacing:0.1em;LINE-HEIGHT:1.3;  '>  I want to share is like this  </p>`

I want to share is like this：
[shareImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLRCn.png)

This is my forms data

`<p style='font-family:宋体;font-size:13.8pt;word-wrap:break-word;text-align:justify;letter-spacing:0.1em;LINE-HEIGHT:1.3;  '>全球手机销量情况表 </p><table border='1'><tr><td rowspan='2'>公司</td><td colspan='2' >2013年第三季度</td><td colspan='2' >2012年第三季度</td></tr><tr><td>万台</td><td>市场份额</td><td>万台</td><td>市场份额</td></tr><tr><td>三星</td><td>11705.4</td><td>25.7%</td><td>9795.7</td><td>22.7%</td></tr><tr><td>诺基亚</td><td>6304.8</td><td>13.8%</td><td>8230.1</td><td>19.1%</td></tr><tr><td>苹果</td><td>3033.0</td><td>6.7%</td><td>2462.0</td><td>5.7%</td></tr><tr><td>LG</td><td>1803.1</td><td>4.0%</td><td>1396.9</td><td>3.2%</td></tr><tr><td>中兴</td><td>1369.6</td><td>3.0%</td><td>1660.6</td><td>3.9%</td></tr><tr><td>其它</td><td>15600.5</td><td>34.2%</td><td>15370.1</td><td>35.7%</td></tr><tr><td>总计</td><td>45564.2</td><td>100.0%</td><td>43102.4</td><td>100.0%</td></tr></table>`

I want to share is like this：
[FormImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCwA9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the problem,the specific method is as follows:

I use this method to the WebView screenshots, then share images can be achieved after screenshots: share UIWebView.

```
- (UIImage *)imageRepresentation{

CGSize boundsSize = self.view.bounds.size;
CGFloat boundsWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat boundsHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;

CGPoint offset = self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset;
[self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

CGFloat contentHeight = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];
while (contentHeight > 0) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(boundsSize);
    [self.webView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [images addObject:image];

    CGFloat offsetY = self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    [self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, offsetY + boundsHeight)];
    contentHeight -= boundsHeight;
}
[self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:offset];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.webView.scrollView.contentSize);
[images enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, boundsHeight * idx, boundsWidth, boundsHeight)];
}];
UIImage *fullImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return fullImage;
```

}

Those are screenshot to share pictures:

[Contains pictures of articles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9OuK.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQyaE.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

-- Swift 3 --

```
// you can share image,string,url, and data. convert your html to data. 
let sharingItem = [image,str,url,data]

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingItem, applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook ]

self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```